# How to disconnect invalid clients immediately on Ratchet PHP?

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

I started learning Ratchet PHP. I did the first tutorial on Ratchet website (http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world) which basically just opens a server and sends incoming text messages to other clients.

I send messages with javascript console in Firefox and It works as expexted.

Meanwhile, without any specific reason I connect to Ratchet server with `telnet localhost 8080`. For sure it does nothing as the server expects `WS` protocol.

At this point, it is obivous that `telnet` is an invalid client for my app. So I don't want it to hang around and user my server's resources.

What can I do for this purpose? Is there an option or parameter I can specify to disconnect this connection or can I detect it easily with serverside code and disconnect it from there with some kind of fingerprint/agent or with a timeout?

Server code:

```
<?php
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use MyApp\Chat;

require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new Chat()
        )
    ),
    8080
);

$server->run();
```

Comment: As-per the RFC, if the client doesn't handshake properly, the server must send an appropriate HTTP response (400 Bad Request is most likely) and disconnect. -- Sounds like a bug to file with the Ratchet devs.

Comment: I believe you can do this using nginx as a proxy for your WebSocket and forward only WS connections to the localhost websocket.  Then any other requests will either be 404'ed or dealt with as HTTP requests.